# Node.js client cert from Windows... how can I tell if the cert is being sent?

Tags: node.js, ssl, client-certificates

I've got a client-side cert secured rest endpoint which works when I hit it via curl using a known cert in Linux-land... That is to say, if I console.log(req.connection.getPeerCertificate()), I see a bunch of stuff. Cool.

... however, when one of my teammates tries to hit the same endpoint from a Windows Machine, req.connection.getPeerCertificate() is an empty object, even though they think they're attaching the cert correctly.

What's the best way to tell if they are, indeed, attaching the cert correctly? How should I go about debugging this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs say](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tlssocket_getpeercertificate_detailed):

> If the peer does not provide a certificate, [`getPeerCertificate`] returns `null` or an empty object.

So you already know that the Windows client is not sending a valid certificate because `getPeerCertificate()` returns an empty object.  Check the `authorizationError` property for additional information about any client certificate errors that may have occurred.

Debug this by finding out why the client isn't sending a certificate.  Are you setting `requestCert: true` in your [server options](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createserver_options_secureconnectionlistener)?  Is the client properly configured?  Is it sending a certificate that can be validated?

Comment: I suspect what you're saying is true, Josh... but here's a dumb question: is it possible that the cert is being sent, but there's some reason I can't decode it correctly? I know that I can decode my sample cert and that all works...

Comment: Is `req.connection.authorizationError` set?

Comment: authorizationError: 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT'

Comment: There you go -- the cert that the Windows client is supplying can't be validated.  My guess is that either the cert chain is incomplete (there's an intermediary that isn't being sent to the server) or the issuing CA isn't trusted.  If the client cert is issued by a nonstandard CA, you have to pass its public key into the server's [`ca` option](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createserver_options_secureconnectionlistener).